# windows store app 8.1 httpclient request failes in local private network

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, httpwebrequest, windows-8.1

http request to receive json fails in private network or even in same system server set with xamp it is working fine with public networks over internet.

i have given internet client&server , private networks capabilities in appxmanifest

code:

```
public static async Task<string> GetStringfromUrl(string url)
    {

        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(GlobalVariables.Web_AccountName,GlobalVariables.Web_AccountPassword);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);



        try
        {
            string responseBodyAsText;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseBodyAsText;

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message +"/n" + ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

in private network it shows authorization exception ,in same system localhost it doesnt pass the line of code.while works all fine in public internet 
please help

Comment: Notice that connecting to localhost is not allowed for security reasons in WinRT. If you have two machines in the same locla network, please provide the full exception description.

Comment: ""Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)""                        .System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException its the exception i tested it removing authentication Credentials and works ,but want to use Credentials any idea

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? What technology are you using in the server side? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

**Information upon which solution to try is based**

"Using network loopback in side-loaded Windows Store apps"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640582.aspx
@ section "Configuring the firewall"

> CheckNetIsolation utility
>
> Windows Firewall also blocks loopback connections for all Windows
>   Store apps by default. A device admin can enable loopback for a
>   Windows Store app using the CheckNetIsolation.exe tool. This tool is
>   available on the command line in any Windows 8.1 installation.

**Solution to try**

Use @ command prompt

```
checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=<package-family-name>
```

Where

```
-a
```

stands for add

```
-n
```

stands for AppContainer Name or Package Family Name (which we care in this case) and

```
<package-family-name>
```

can be found @ packaging.appmanifest @ packaging

> CheckNetIsolation.exe usage
>
> CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt [operation] [-n=] [-p=]
>         List of operations: -a -d -c -s
>         List of arguments: -n= -p= -?

**Context within the issue was encountered in my case**

During testing a Windows (Store App) Portable Library via a Windows (Store App) Unit Test which accessed a localhost self hosting WebAPI setup-ed by a parallel running console app.

**Notes**

I too tried the Capabilities, you reffer to, to no avail and after fixing the problem I actually reverted back to original configuration which did not use any of those 2 additional ones (Internet (Client & Server), Private Networks (Client & Server)) to see if they mattered and the solution above still worked, probably because those have to do with having your app behave as a server and handle requests.

*Let me know if this resolves the issue and if yes don't forget to accept the answer!*